# jQuery does not send POST data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page, quiz.php, which shows quiz questions. I want to send the data for a question type using AJAX. I return to the same page, which loads a new questions.

Now what you see is that on submit I create an `alert` just for while coding to check the ID's are correct, which they are. After this alert, I want to set the POST. For now I am just sending the Id inside `box1`, but all four should be there in the end.

When my page reloads, I want to see the ID using

```
$test = isset($_POST['box']);  
var_dump($test);
```

See my code below

```html
<?php
  //logtime.php
  $test = isset($_POST['box']);
  var_dump($test);
  var_dump($_REQUEST);
  //rest of code that uses $uid
?>

  <form method="POST" autocomplete="off" id="form">
    <?php showPhoto($question[1], $question[0]); ?>
    <div class="row createWhitespaceBottom" id="fotoblok">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="hidden" name="questionId" class="form-control" id="questionId" value="<?php echo $question[0]; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="questionType" class="form-control" id="questionType" value="<?php echo $question[1]; ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="dragBox" id="box1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="dragBox" id="box2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="dragBox" id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="dragBox" id="box4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="input-group-btn createWhitespaceTop">
      <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()"  id="antwoordblok2" class="btn btn-primary">Opslaan</button>
     </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {
    var box1 = $("#box1 :first-child").attr('id');
    var box2 = $("#box2 :first-child").attr('id');
    var box3 = $("#box3 :first-child").attr('id');
    var box4 = $("#box4 :first-child").attr('id');
    alert(box1 + " " + box2 + " " + box3 + " " + box4);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'quiz.php',
      data: {
        box: box1
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So you want to send id inside the ajax call.

Comment: Yes. I want to send the id inside var box1 using a AJAX call, so I can handle it using php

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not stopping the form from it's default behaviour. Change your jQuery to this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); //this will stop the form submitting and let you do your ajax
    //etc.
});
```

Form attribute `action` by default is an empty string- which refers to the page it was sent from. So you're posting the form to itself, not even going to your ajax request.

See here:

[event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

[form (scroll to action)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="antwoordblok2" class="btn btn-primary">Opslaan</button>
```

change type "submit" to "button" and redirect it or reload it on success.

It will call ajax in asynchronous and when the call succeeds you can take the desired action.